# CameraX - Unable to get camera ID for use case androidx.camera.core.Preview-4817149b-004d-42b8-a103-ea998038268b - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: androidx, android-jetpack, android-camerax

While implementing the code from Google CodeLabs I am getting this crash report while starting the CameraActivity - [CameraX - Google Code Labs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started/#0)

Logs:

> Process: in.novopay.novoloan, PID: 5845
>       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to get camera ID for use case
>   androidx.camera.core.Preview-4817149b-004d-42b8-a103-ea998038268b
>           at androidx.camera.camera2.impl.Camera2DeviceSurfaceManager.getCameraIdFromConfig(Camera2DeviceSurfaceManager.java:310)
>           at androidx.camera.camera2.impl.Camera2DeviceSurfaceManager.requiresCorrectedAspectRatio(Camera2DeviceSurfaceManager.java:268)
>           at androidx.camera.core.Preview.updateUseCaseConfig(Preview.java:387)
>           at androidx.camera.core.UseCase.(UseCase.java:92)
>           at androidx.camera.core.Preview.(Preview.java:99) at in.novopay.uicontrollibrary.activities.CameraActivity.startCamera(CameraActivity.kt:94)
>           at in.novopay.uicontrollibrary.activities.CameraActivity.access$startCamera(CameraActivity.kt:30)
>           at in.novopay.uicontrollibrary.activities.CameraActivity$checkPermission$1.run(CameraActivity.kt:45)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
>        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Option does not exist: Option{id=camerax.core.camera.lensFacing, valueClass=class
>   androidx.camera.core.CameraX$LensFacing, token=null}

```
// This is an arbitrary number we are using to keep tab of the permission
// request. Where an app has multiple context for requesting permission,
// this can help differentiate the different contexts
private const val REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 10

// This is an array of all the permission specified in the manifest
private val REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)

class CameraActivity : AppCompatActivity(), LifecycleOwner {

    lateinit var viewFinder: TextureView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera)

        viewFinder = findViewById(R.id.texture_view)
//        startCamera()
        checkPermission();
    }

    fun checkPermission() {
        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
            viewFinder.post { startCamera() }
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS)
        }

        // Every time the provided texture view changes, recompute layout
        viewFinder.addOnLayoutChangeListener { _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _ ->
            updateTransform()
        }
    }

    /**
     * Process result from permission request dialog box, has the request
     * been granted? If yes, start Camera. Otherwise display a toast
     */
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS) {
            if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
                viewFinder.post {
                    startCamera()
                }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "Permissions not granted by the user.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                finish()
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check if all permission specified in the manifest have been granted
     */
    private fun allPermissionsGranted() = REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS.all {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                baseContext, it) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    private fun startCamera() {
        // Create configuration object for the viewfinder use case
        val previewConfig = PreviewConfig.Builder().apply {
            setTargetAspectRatio(Rational(1, 1))
            setTargetResolution(Size(640, 640))
        }.build()

        // Build the viewfinder use case
        val preview = Preview(previewConfig)

        // Every time the viewfinder is updated, recompute layout
        preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener {

            // To update the SurfaceTexture, we have to remove it and re-add it
            val parent = viewFinder.parent as ViewGroup
            parent.removeView(viewFinder)
            parent.addView(viewFinder, 0)

            viewFinder.surfaceTexture = it.surfaceTexture
            updateTransform()
        }

        // Bind use cases to lifecycle
        // If Android Studio complains about "this" being not a LifecycleOwner
        // try rebuilding the project or updating the appcompat dependency to
        // version 1.1.0 or higher.
        CameraX.bindToLifecycle(this, preview)
    }

    private fun updateTransform() {
        val matrix = Matrix()

        // Compute the center of the view finder
        val centerX = viewFinder.width / 2f
        val centerY = viewFinder.height / 2f

        // Correct preview output to account for display rotation
        val rotationDegrees = when(viewFinder.display.rotation) {
            Surface.ROTATION_0 -> 0
            Surface.ROTATION_90 -> 90
            Surface.ROTATION_180 -> 180
            Surface.ROTATION_270 -> 270
            else -> return
        }

        matrix.postRotate(-rotationDegrees.toFloat(), centerX, centerY)

        // Finally, apply transformations to our TextureView
        viewFinder.setTransform(matrix)
    }
}
```

Comment: I get this error too.

Answer (score 12):

```
val previewConfig = PreviewConfig.Builder().apply {
            setTargetAspectRatio(Rational(1,1))
            setTargetResolution(Size(640,640))
            setLensFacing(androidx.camera.core.CameraX.LensFacing.BACK)
        }.build()
```

Comment: Could you explain how your answer fixes the bug?

Comment: I have setLensFacing() in  PreviewConfig.Builder but the same problem reproduced

Comment: The [Release notes for alpha-04](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/camera#1.0.0-alpha04) Say.  

_Fixed issue when setLensFacing was not called for a use case, resulting in java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to get camera ID for use case._